# How do I find the list of sources/mirrors for my country, Jordan?

Tags: package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager, software-sources

I am using Ubuntu Focal 20.04.4 LTS and recently I had a problem with my source list.

I tried all the solutions on the internet and nothing works but when I turn on the VPN the problem disappears. Now I tried to install a package. The problem is my source list is not up to date and the packages are still old versions.

How do I find the source list for the country Jordan?

My current `sources.list`:

```
deb http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multive>
deb-src http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe mul>

deb http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe>
deb-src http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted univ>

deb http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted univers>
deb-src http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted uni>

deb http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted univer>
deb-src http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted un>

deb http://jo.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://jo.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

Comment: If you had used "code formatting" it wouldn't have seen them as links. I have edited your Question to supply the needed formatting. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. I have not removed your "make it not a URL" changes. Also, are the "`>`" characters at end-of-line part of the file? What do you mean by "`mul>`"? [Edit] your Question to repair.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by looking at the official [Mirrors listings](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) on Launchpad, and then find a mirror closer to you that is up to date.  This list is sorted by country.

Based on what I can tell from the mirrors list from awm's answer, and the mirrors list on Launchpad, there are no *actual* archive mirrors in Jordan itself, and `jo.archive.ubuntu.com` looks like it's pointed at the main repository servers run by Canonical.

I would find a mirror in a country nearer to yours and then try using those mirrors.  I would also suggest you use "Up to Date" mirrors or least-out-of-sync mirrors, otherwise you might not get the latest updates.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: my new source list:
deb http://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/ focal main 
deb-src http://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/ focal main 
when I try : sudo apt-get update
the output:
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:2 http://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 194.124.244.12 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 194.124.244.12 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: when I connect to the open VPN its works /// I don't know why

Comment: Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Hit:2 http://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Reading package lists... Done
 this output after i used the vpn

Comment: It sounds like you're being blocked in Jordan by your ISP possibly.  That's supported by the fact that when you VPN it works.  That may be a problem at your local government's restrictions level, and they may not permit you to go to other mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
wget -qO - mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt
```

to get a list of active mirrors, then use traceroute and ping to see which is the closest to your network.

Answer (score 0):

Another item that you might try:  In the graphical application "Software & Updates" under the tab marked "Ubuntu Software".  If you choose "Other" for the "Download From" then Ubuntu can run tests against the mirrors to determine which is 'best' for your location - click the button "Select Best Server"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer //I didn't find  "Software & Updates" in my OS // there is just "Software" and it's just an app store or something like that

Comment: @ubuntu_user123  Very strange - I'll update my answer to show what the program looks like when called up in the activities window